# How do tell if a file is opened for reading/writing in Android?

Tags: java, android, io, android-file

Here is a code snippet where I am opening a file for writing with two `FileOutputStream`s at the same time.

```
FileOutputStream fis = null;
File openFile = new File("myfile");
try {
    fis = new FileOutputStream(openFile);
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Opened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FileNotFound", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}

// now try to open it again
FileOutputStream fis2 = null;
try {
    fis2 = new FileOutputStream(openFile);
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Opened2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}
catch (Exception e1) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception: " + e1.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}
```

I end up getting two `Toast` messages, "Opened" and "Opened2".

I need to make sure I don't open a file for reading/writing/deleting that is currently open for writing by another instance.  How to I ensure I do not modify a file that is currently open for writing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to make sure I don't open a file for reading/writing/deleting
>   that is currently open for writing by another instance.

What do you mean by another instance?

- If this is another thread in your application use the synchronization for read/write methods.
- If this is another process created by yourself (application, service etc.) use exclusive [`FileLock`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html) to coordinate file read/write operations between processes.
- If this is another process you don't control (i.e. created by someone else) you can check whether file is currently opened by inspecting `/proc/…/fd/` tree, as [lsof](http://google.com/codesearch#2wSbThBwwIw/toolbox/lsof.c&q=lsof.c) utility does. However this usually requires you to have root privileges.

Hope that give you a clue. Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Isn't there a way to say "I'm about to read that file, please make sure other processes cannot write it until I'm done" ? I'm using a SharedPreferences and they get lost after a while, but I can't use FileLock for them when using Android API.

Answer (score 1):

[FileObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html) might help you.

Comment: Having 2 processes (same app) read the same preference file, I tried using FileObserver to reload preferences. Turns out this is completely unreliable (didn't find out why) and one process didn't reload preferences after it was modified by another! Even thought I made sure the observer was kept alive.

Answer (score 0):

You could just perform a null check

```
if (null == fis)
// then create output stream
```

If fis was opened earlier, it wouldn't be null, and you wouldn't end up opening another output stream.

Comment: You obviously misread the question... there's `fis` and `fis2` there...